# Hydrogenation of cycloalkanes

Tags: organic-chemistry

Why can we not hydrogenate or brominate etc. on cycloalkanes to convert into linear molecule? And are there any exceptions to this?

Comment: Well, the $\ce{C-C}$ bond in cycloalkanes is the same as $\ce{C-C}$ bond in alkanes - that is, quite solid. Except when it is strained like in cyclopropane, which you indeed **can** brominate, hydrogenate and do whatever else.